# Combine Excel rows with duplicate keywords, but unique values in other columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, deduplication

I have an Excel sheet with keywords in column B. For each row there will be a value in one cell somewhere between column E and column CR.

So, line 3 will have a keyword in column B be and a value in column AQ.

Line 4 might have the same keyword in column B and a different value in column CK

Each instance of a given keyword will have exactly one value between E and CR, the rest of those cells will be blank.

I need a way to combine all instances of each keyword into one row with all of the different values from E-CR.

That is, using the example above, I'd like to end up where line 3 has values in both AQ and CK. And then I would delete line 4.

I have several of these worksheets with around 4,000 lines each.

[image]

Edited: [This file](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=BE7B997F65AF147B!7703&ithint=file%2Cxlsx&app=Excel&authkey=!AC-_cVIu31LPhYU) contains a sample of the raw data in lines 2 to 15 and an example of the desired results in lines 20-23.

Comment: Meghan, It sounds little complicated so my suggestion is share some sample data along with expected result, will help us to fix the issue.

Comment: Are the values in E:CR numbers, text, or a combination?  If it's numbers, do you need to be able to use the result in calculations?  Can you give some examples?  If they're numbers, just sum the range.  If they're text, concatenate the range.  Or, are you talking about collapsing all rows for a keyword into one that contains the values from the different rows in their same columns?  Can you mock up a simple example or add a screenshot?

Comment: This file [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnsUr2V_mXu-vBcvv3FSLt9Sz4WF) contains a sample of the raw data in lines 2 to 15 and an example of the desired results in lines 20-22.

Comment: correction 20-23

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1401741/edit) and include the sample data and desired result in your question (not as an outside link): that way anyone else with a similar question will be able to reference yours even if the link goes dead.

Comment: If I knew how to do that, I would be happy to do so.

Comment: Pasting the contents of the file make it unreadable so I've added a screen shot. I can't find a way to attach the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. It will require 3 copy/paste and 4 formula drag fill duplicates.

1) Use this array formula to create a list of unique values for column B:

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( $B$3:$B$16, MATCH( 0, COUNTIF( $B$26:B26, $B$3:$B$16), 0)), "<blank>")
```

Paste this formula to the cell where the list of unique values will begin.
Edit the first COUNTIF argument "$B$26:B26" to the cell address directly above the cell you have pasted into. Besure to preserve the absolute ($) references.
You can edit or remove the word "<blank>" but you will likely want to leave a set of double quotes (whatever you put here will be the *fill* when there are no more unique values but will be replaced if new unique values are added to the data range).
Edit both occurrences of the "$B$3:$B$16" address to the absolute address range of your Description column data. It can be larger than the current data, but do not overlap with the formula just pasted.
Finally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make this an array formula.

2) Copy drag down the formula to duplicate it to the cells below and see all the unique values or further to allow for new unique values.

3) To add a column to the left of your unique values, paste the following formula to the left of your first paste:

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( A$3:A$16, MATCH( TRUE, IF( $B$3:$B$16=$B27, NOT( ISBLANK( A$3:A$16)), FALSE), 0)), "<blank>")
```

Edit all the addresses. Both of the "A$3:A$16" address ranges become your Item Code data range.
The "$B$3:$B$16" once again is changed to the absolute values for your Description data range.
Finally the "$B27" should be the adjacent column to the right of your paste (the address of the cell containing the first unique value and the first pasted formula). You will want to preserve the absolute and relative notations, only changing the column letters and row numbers.
Again, change the "<blank>" keeping in mind the previous points on this.
Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make this an array formula.

4) Copy drag down this formula to duplicate it to the cells below as far as the first formula was dragged.

5) Almost there. Click on the cell where you pasted this formula.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> then click on the cell to the right of the unique formula (column C of the sample sheet) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>. Excel will update the relative references.
Edit the formula, removing the word <blank> but leaving the set of double quotes.
After changing the formula you must again press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make this an array formula. (last time)

6) Final Step- a two part drag. Copy drag down the formula to duplicate it to the cells below as far as the first two formulas were dragged. Let go of the drag button (or mechanism) but do not deselect the column of copied cells (they will all be duplicate to the right in the second part of this step).
Now copy drag right the formulas to duplicate them as far right as you have columns (CR on the sample sheet).

Note: The values propagated by the second two formulas are the first non blank value found for the keyword in each column. This is especially applicable to the columns outside of the scope of the stated problem, namely the Item Code, Price and Vendor columns. But it also applies to the scope of the stated problem if there happen to be duplicates within any particular column (E:CR) for a singular keyword, the first non blank value corresponding to that keyword will be displayed.